# Get Most Recent GIT Commit Info For Each Requested File

Tags: git

This will get me the commit details of the request files, BUT ONLY if they were included in the very last commit:

```
git log origin/master -1 --oneline -- file1 file2
```

But how can I get the last commit (most recent) for each file requested ?

Comment: Every file is included in _every_ commit, so what does "the last commit" even mean? What exactly are you trying to find out?

Comment: @Matt is correct. All files that are beeing tracked  are part of all the revisions.... but I figured out you meant the last time each time was modified

Answer (score 1):

Probably like this:

```
git ls-tree -r origin/master | while read file; do echo $file $( git log --pretty=%h -n 1 origin/master -- "$file" ); done
```